# Display different time from one field value

Tags: datetime

I have field to display event start date and time. This field uses date module's widget. I need display time of event start for different time zones. For example:

Eventname - starttime for Tallin: 05.07.2015 01:54

Eventname - starttime for Boston: 05.07.2015 09:54 (+8 Hours)

How can I add +8 hours to date field value and display result on node?

Comment: Why don't you use user's timezone? so that each user will see event based on his/her own timezone?

Comment: Because I need display start time of some event on American's server for Russian users. This event is added on site with start time for Boston. I need autoconvert this time for Moscow time, but Boston's time also should be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Well you are better off writing a custom module or using a function that can swap out a timezone variable instead of manually calculating by adding 8 hours...
But if that's what you want here is one way of achieving this..

Create a node template for that content type or specific node (whichever suits your scenario).

In the template file you can use:

```
 <?php
    // Your date field. note the appended 'field_' at the start of the machine name.
    $date = new DateTime($content['field_YOUR_FIELD_MACHINE_NAME']['#items'][0]['value']);

    // Boston date field
    $boston_date = $date;
    $boston_date ->modify("+8 hours");
    $boston_date ->format("d.m.Y H:i");

    //Outputs your date field with 8 hours added to it.
    print 'Eventname - starttime for Boston: ' . $boston_date;
 ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for help! But this solution crashes my site without any error message. I don't know why(

Comment: Where are you placing the code? I tested my code on a fresh install of d7 and it works great with a node template.